Where is the .vscode folder located?
I am trying to look for a folder called .vscode and I can't find it anywhere on my C drive. Is it hidden? If it is, where should I look for it so that i can unhide it.
I tried searching for it manually on my pc and it took too long and still didn't find anything. i checked the in appdata and still couldn't find it.
I have a python program. It is inside a folder. Thus the project folder is that folder itself. (documents/python). I have ran the code. No .vscode folder has been created. Hence why I am asking for help.
This is not similar to the question "what is the vscode folder" since I can't find the folder itself, I know that an electron orbits a hydrogen nucleus, but I can't find its location.
Here is the python.code-workspace file's code
{
"folders": [ 
    {
        "path": "."
    }
],
"settings": {
    "emmet.preferences": {}
}


It is indeed hidden. It is usually located in the specific VSCode workspace/project folder.

I checked hidden items and i still cant find it

This question is similar to: what is .vscode folder? and why did it automatically created when I run live server?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Well, what makes you believe it exists at all then?

I was told that whenever you ran code, its automatically created in your project folder

I am unsure as to why my question is being downvoted, clearly this is a unique question as THERE IS NO .VSCODE FOLDER BEING CREATED.

You should tell us more about what you are trying to do. Do you have a VSCode project?  Can you access it's settings.json as documented in the link in the answer? If you can, then you can know the path of where it is located.

Please provide [mcve] that shows exact step-by-step instructions how you created your project in VS Code.

Please look at my recent edit.

You can just change any setting (switch to the "Workspace" tab in your settings page!). It seems VSCode doesn't create .vscode for every directory and only saves settings if you change something. If you can run your code without changing the default settings then VSCode doesn't have to create a settings file.

Still no change, the folder doesn't exist and it's driving CRAZY!!

Should I create this folder on my own since this software is faulty?

Can you open settings.json file by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P and typing settings in there and then selecting "Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)" ?

Again, did you follow the steps above? What happened when you did?

I replied but it had unformatted code and I deleted it.
I did do the steps. I found no settings.json file. However I found a Python.code-workspace file instead in my project folder.

These steps are not requiring from you to "find" it. Did you find the "Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)" command?

Yes, I did find the command as I mentioned earlier.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

So it is opening the workspace file? That's legit too. So looks like you have a multi-root workspace configured. In this case the .vscode directory might not be there as everything is configured in the workspace file. See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces . It might however have a .vscode per folder

Legit? I don't take any offense but do you think I am a child? Anyways, I guess I don't need the .vscode file then. I'll close the question.

Wait how do you close a question without deleting it?

Eh? How "legit" implies what I am thinking about your age? Is it US vs British thing? "Legit" is pretty much a shorthand for "legitimate" . you don't close a question, we do. You can however delete it.

Alternatively you can accept one of the answers. But since there is currently no correct answer as it seems, you can answer it yourself and accept your own answer.

According to official documentation:

A VS Code "workspace" is usually just your project root folder. Workspace settings as well as debugging and task configurations are stored at the root in a .vscode folder.


"Workspace settings as well as debugging and task configurations are stored at the root in a .vscode folder."
I know this, however I can't find such a vscode folder in my project root folder.

I tested this as well. The definition what it is doesn't tell us when it will be created. It only appeared in the directory once I changed settings using the "Workspace" tab in VSCode's settings.

The .vscode folder is usually a hidden directory located in the root of your project folder.
The .vscode folder typically appears in one of the following places:

In the root of your project directory (e.g., C:\Users<YourUsername>\Documents\MyProject.vscode).
It might be within the C:\Users<YourUsername>.vscode if it's related to user-wide settings or extensions.

If you don't find the .vscode folder, it may not have been created yet. You can create this folder manually in your project directory if you need to store specific settings or extensions there.
You can know more information through The documentation

The (workspace) .vscode directory doesn't get automatically created (in the absence of extensions that write changes to workspace settings). It's just a regular directory. If it doesn't exist, you can create it. Create it right under/inside the workspace folder. Ex. by clicking an empty section of the Explorer View, and then click the "create new folder/directory" action button at the top right of the Explorer View, and then name it ".vscode". You can also create it by running Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON) in the command palette (see Is there a way to make a settings.json simply on a project?)
